# MVC - View changes display of data that is sorted in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting, razor

I am working on an MVC application where it displays sorted data in a grid. It's pretty simple, The model gets the data and the view displays the output. However the view can format the output in a way that it makes the underlying data look unsorted

For example, the model runs this query and it's output is properly sorted:

```
Select ClassName, IsActiveClassAssignment from classtable order by ClassName
```

However, the view can change the display of a ClassName depending on the value of the other field in the viewmodel. For example: Here's a snippet of the  view cshtml.

```
<span data-bind="if:ClassName==null">&nbsp;</span><span data-bind="text: ClassName, visible:IsActiveClassAssignment" />
```

This leads to displaying seemingly blank classnames within the sorted output.

One easy way to solve this is to push the cshtml logic shown above down into the data access/model layer. For example

```
 select, CASE WHEN IsActiveClassAssignment = 1 THEN '' ELSE ClassName END as ClassName,IsActiveClassAssignment order by ClassName
```

But this doesn't seem right. There are cshtml code snippets like this all over the application and pushing that type of 'display' logic into the model doesn't seem right... or is it?

How best to solve for this in an MVC application?

Comment: do you do this sorting locally to the current model using js or call a controller again resulting in different model? you can have duplicate value for the classname, say cl-val, so even if the text is empty, you can get that from cl-val attribute, so you don't need to do case every now and then.

Comment: The application reloads the model via an ajax call to the controller which returns a new sorted model(depending on what sort criteria the user specified).  Though your suggestion works and though this example is simple the actual display manipulation is very complex (I chose not to show the actual complexity in the example above) and as I mentioned above, it doesn't feel right to be pushing this type of logic down into the modal/data access layer.... or does MVC dictate that it should?